# A variant of Borsuk Problem based on 'Least Width'

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, discrete-geometry

**Definitions:** The diameter of a convex region is the greatest distance between any pair of points in the region. The least width of a 2D convex region can be defined as the least distance between any pair of parallel lines (in higher dimensions, hyperplanes) that touch the region.

The following question is a variant of the Borsuk problem which focusses on diameter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%27s_conjecture):

**Question:** Can every planar convex region with least width = 1 be partitioned into 4 convex pieces such that every piece has least width at least 1/2?

**Remarks:** If the answer to above is "yes", one can ask the generalization: can every d-dimensional convex region with least width = 1 be cut into 2^d convex pieces such that each piece has least width at lest 1/2? If the answer is "no", one can ask for a better bound on least width.

One can also ask, given a general fraction *f*, to find that number of pieces such that the least width among them is at least *f* when any convex body with unit least width is partitioned; and perhaps try to extend the Borsuk problem itself by asking given an *f*, at least how many pieces are needed so that the diameter of each piece is less than *f*.

The question could be reformulated for laminar bodies with quantities such as moment of inertia replacing least width.

Comment: What do you think it's the role of algebraic topology in this problem? I'm curious.

Comment: The guess is that techniques of algebraic topology might be needed to resolve this question. If you judge otherwise, pls comment / take off that tag.

Comment: I'm just curious, I was recently proving the Borsuk-Ulam theorem in a graduate course. I wouldn't know how to model convexity with homotopical notions. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know. But many questions in discrete geometry have been attacked and settled with tools from algebraic topology as was for example this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SfXqTENV_Q&t=21s

Comment: What does it mean for a pair of parallel lines to touch the region?

Comment: For any convex region C, given any direction, there are a pair of supporting parallel lines - lines in that direction that passes thru points on the boundary of C but do not pass thru any point in the interior of C.